# Expressions in PlotLegends

Tags: plotting, special-functions, legending

When the order of the Bessel function is negative, it will automatically be evaluated in `PlotLegends`.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, -5, 0}]], {x, 0, 14}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> TraditionalForm /@ {x, BesselJ[n, x]},
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Yellow, Green, Blue, Purple}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

However, I want to keep the original expression in `PlotLegends`, so I modified the code.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

leg[n_] := Row[{Subscript["J", n], "(x)"}];

Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, -5, 0}]], {x, 0, 14}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> TraditionalForm /@ {x, BesselJ[n, x]},
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Yellow, Green, Blue, Purple}, 
 PlotLegends -> {Table[leg[n], {n, -5, 0}]}]
```

I was wondering if there is a more elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[BesselJ[n, x], {n, -5, 0}]], {x, 0, 14}, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> TraditionalForm /@ {x, BesselJ[n, x]},
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Red, Yellow, Green, Blue, Purple}
 , PlotLegends -> Table[BesselJ[ToString@n, x], {n, -5, 0}]
```